# Boruta Shadow Feature has the highest Z-Score

Tags: boruta

I used the Boruta-SHAP algorithm (https://github.com/Ekeany/Boruta-Shap) for feature selection. The algorithm confirmed two features as relevant and rejected the other ones. Still the highest Z_Score goes to a shadow feature (see picture).

My question is: are the two accepted features relevant even though a shadow feature has higher score than them? [image]